# How to return a list item view in a custom adapter with asynchronous image loading

Tags: android

So I have a view holder I set up in my custom list adapter

```
static class ViewHolder {

    static TextView album;
    static TextView artist;
    static TextView title;
    static TextView duration;

    static ImageView albumArt;

}
```

I'm able to adapt the text views without difficulty. Here is a code summary:

```
// Set view holder references 

viewHolder.album = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.album);
viewHolder.artist = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.artist);
viewHolder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
viewHolder.albumArt = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.album_art);
viewHolder.duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);

// Set values to referenced view objects 

viewHolder.album.setText(songObject.album);
viewHolder.artist.setText(songObject.artist);
viewHolder.title.setText(songObject.title);
SongHolder.duration.setText( /** Some Code **/ )
viewHolder.albumArt.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(songObject.albumArtURI));

// Return the converted view

return convertView;
```

The album art however, is blocking the main UI thread from scrolling through the list in a smooth fashion, so I am trying to load the album art asynchronously. Now is it possible to do something like this with the album art?

Instead of doing this

```
viewHolder.albumArt.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(songObject.albumArtURI));
```

I do this

```
ImageLoader(viewHolder);
```

Or could I pass just a "part" of the object like this

```
ImageLoader(viewHolder.albumArt);
```

What about this way?

```
 viewHolder.albumArt.setImageBitmap(ImageLoader(AlbumArtURI))
```

Will any of these methods work once I have a proper asynchronous image loader implemented?

Thanks

Comment: Declare ViewHolder viewHolder = null global. and in getView() => viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

Comment: Yes, both method will work when you have proper asynchronous image loader

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK What about this? `viewHolder.albumArt.setImageBitmap(ImageLoader(AlbumArtURI))`

Answer (score 0):

Can I suggest [Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/) to you? It'll do all the work to you.

Here is a piece of code that I'm using to load images into a List Adapter:

```
    public ListAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.getTag();

        if(img == null) {
            img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
            v.setTag(img);
        }
            // get the url from the data you passed to the `Map`
            //String url = ((Map) getItem(position)).get();
            String url =  ((Map<String, String>)getItem(position)).get("imagem");
            // do Picasso
            Picasso.with(v.getContext()).load(url).fit().into(img);

            // return the view
            return v;
        }
}
```

Comment: I tried using universal image loader, but it seemed like it was more work to figure out how to use, and additionally the minimum API level was 21 when I'm trying to go as low as possible... maybe if the API level is low enough, or it has a support library or something, then I can use it...

Answer (score 0):

use ViewHolder pattern for smooth scrolling using this tutorial

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-viewholder-pattern-example.html

use asynchronus image loading library

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

use ViewHolder pattern and Glide like this

```
 public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView img_Coach;
        TextView tv_coach;
   }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
                    context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.img_Coach = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_coach);
            holder.tv_coach = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_coach);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.tv_coach.setText(name);
        Glide.with(mActivity)
                .load(urlimage)
                .centerCrop()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.home_no_image)
                .crossFade()
                .into(holder.img_Coach);

        return convertView;
    }
```